# Transition to red instantly, after 2 seconds transition to blue

Tags: css

This is the only thing I could think of.

```css
#div {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  transition: 1s;
}

#div:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

#div:hover {
  transition-delay: 2s;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">

</div>
```

It'll instead ignore the first `#div:hover`

EDIT:

Alright this seemed to work.

```
#div:hover {
    animation: fade 3s forwards;
}
@keyframes fade {
    0%, 66% {background-color: red}
    100% {background-color: blue}
}
```

but how do I make it fade out in reverse?

Comment: Of course this is ignored, because you have overwritten the second rule with the third one - that is one of the very basic principles of how CSS works ... // There is only one hover state, you can not introduce a delay using that alone. Use an animation instead of a transition.

Comment: U can use setTimeout function to achieve this

Comment: @FridayAmeh not necessary

Comment: If you can post you html so we can help you

Comment: Oo sorry I actually didn't see you div

Comment: Alright, I'm learning how to do animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve with `animation`.

```css
#div {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: black;
}

#div:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  animation: delayed 4s forwards;
}

@keyframes delayed {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  51% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div">

</div>
```

Comment: Alright so by myself I got it do basically this but it ended in black. Phiter's example did pretty much the same thing. But how do I make it do the fade between black - red - blue? I'm not really learning much from this.

Comment: They answered what you asked. Try to ask in one go, not piece by piece.

Answer (score 0):

The second `:hover` is overwriting the first and the transition-delay will always be 2 seconds.

I guess you'll need to create an animation for that:

```css
#div {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: black;
}

#div:hover {
  animation: redtoblue 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes redtoblue{
  0%, 65.9%{
    background-color: red;
  }
  
  66%, 100%{
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div">

</div>
```